# How to use Nokogiri to get the full HTML without any text content

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, xpath, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri to get a page's full HTML but with all of the text stripped out.

I tried this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
x = "<html>  <body>  <div class='example'><span>Hello</span></div></body></html>"
y = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(x).xpath("//*[not(text())]").each { |a| a.children.remove }
puts y.to_s
```

This outputs:

```
<div class="example"></div>
```

I've also tried running it without the `children.remove` part:

```
y = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(x).xpath("//*[not(text())]")
puts y.to_s
```

But then I get:

```
<div class="example"><span>Hello</span></div>
```

But what I actually want is:

```
<html><body><div class='example'><span></span></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This is a very aggressive approach. Tags like `<script>`, `<style>`, and `<noscript>` also have child `text()` nodes containing CSS, HTML, and JS that you might not want to filter out depending on your use case.

If you operate on the parsed document instead of capturing the return value of your iterator, you'll be able to remove the text nodes, and then return the document:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = "<html>  <body>  <div class='example'><span>Hello</span></div></body></html>"

# Parse HTML
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(html)

puts doc.inner_html
# => "<html>  <body>  <div class=\"example\"><span>Hello</span></div>\n</body>\n</html>"

# Remove text nodes from parsed document
doc.xpath("//text()").each { |t| t.remove }

puts doc.inner_html
# => "<html><body><div class=\"example\"><span></span></div></body></html>"
```

Comment: Thank you, @ezkl! This is super helpful. Curious though why you say it's not a good solution to the problem?

Comment: @jayp I'll update my answer to reflect that it really depends on your use case, but if you were to apply this exact approach to more complex webpages, you'd end up dropping child text nodes between functional tags like `<style>`, `<script>`, `<noscript>`, etc.